# Select unique field values with condition

Tags: sql, sql-server

I`m new at SQL and my problem is:

I have a table like

```
  card shop time      date
    1   1   0000    20171001
    2   2   0125    20171002
    2   1   0344    20171002
    3   3   0342    20171103
    4   5   1334    20171104
    4   4   1225    20171105
    5   4   1452    20171106
```

I need to select two fields (`card`(`card` must be unique) and `shop`) by the minimum value of the columns `time` and `date` (`date` is in priority).

The result should look like this:

```
  card shop time    date
    1   1   0000    20171001
    2   2   0125    20171002
    3   3   0342    20171103
    4   5   1334    20171104
    5   4   1452    20171106
```

Thank you in advance!

Comment: Why are 4 different DBMS tagged?

Comment: @RaymondNijland corrected, sry

Comment: Why are 2 different DBMS tagged?

Comment: @Strawberry where? :D

Answer (score 3, accepted):

For SQL Server you could use `WITH TIES`

```
select top 1 with ties *
from yourTable
order by row_number() over (partition by card order by date asc, time asc)
```

Comment: Can you elaborate?

Comment: its working if i remove "shop" from this part: (partition by card, shop order by date asc, time asc)

Comment: I see where the issue is now with how I interpreted your data. I made the edit. Good catch

Answer (score 1):

you can use sub-query and aggregate function

```
select * from yourtable t 
where t.date in (select min(date) from yourtable  t1
                         where t.card=t1.card )
```

Comment: i assume you mean`where t.card=t1.card` here? `where t1.card=t1.card` looks wrong..

Comment: I would add the shop to the correlation to prevent u expected results... and date actually otherwise it could be wrong.

Comment: how i can take DATE here?

Comment: @Alex where you want to take date?

Comment: @ZaynulAbadinTuhin I want the date and time taken into account in the calculation. (the date in this case takes precedence)